# Hibernate or SQL Query M-N member of with collections?

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

Given a class which has an @ElementCollection of Strings, and given an input collection of Strings:

```
public class FooBar {
   @ElementCollection
   private Set<String> tags
}

Set<String> queryTags;
```

How can I query the two following scenarios:

1. Return all FooBar fb where queryTags has at least one match in fb.tags
2. Return all FooBar fb where all Strings in queryTag match an element in fb.tags (queryTag is a subcollection of fb.tags)

Note: I'm not asking if the two collections are equal.

Obviously, I can query all and perform the collection comparison in code, or I can do:

```
for(String tag : queryTags){
   createQuery("from FooBar fb where :t member of fb.tags").setString("t", tag)
}
```

Both ways seem incredibly inefficient, but I don't know if vanilla SQL or HQL support any query support for collections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ```
   select fb 
   from FooBar fb 
   left join fb.tags t
   where t in ( :queryTags )
   ```
2. ```
   select fb 
   from FooBar fb 
   where fb.id not in (
       select id
       from FooBar
       left join tags t
       where t not in ( :queryTags )
   )
   ```

Where the queryTags is set with:

```
session.createQuery(queryString).setParameterList( "queryTags ", queryTags ).list();
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test this out in the next few days!