# Hibernate Query to match mapped entity collection with at least one element in given collection, ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

My owner Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "SubscriptionEntity")
@Table(name = "SUBSCRIPTION", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")})
 
public class SubscriptionEntity implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer subscriptionId;
 
    @Column(name = "SUBS_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String subscriptionName;
     
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="READER_SUBSCRIPTIONS", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="ID")}
                                        , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private Set<ReaderEntity> readers;
 
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Mapped Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "ReaderEntity")
@Table(name = "READER", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "EMAIL"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "USERNAME"})
 
public class ReaderEntity implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer readerId;
 
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String email;
 
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String username;
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="readers") 
    private Set<SubscriptionEntity> subscriptions;
 
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Now, I have a `subscriptionList` which contains few subscriptions. I want a paged list of `ReaderEntity` objects whose subscriptions belong to at least one in the `subscriptionList`. i.e. The intersection of `ReaderEntity.subscriptions` and `subscriptionList` should be at least one.

I have referred to this post and written a query:
[Hibernate or SQL Query M-N member of with collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846512/hibernate-or-sql-query-m-n-member-of-with-collections)

```
@Query("SELECT r FROM ReaderEntity r LEFT JOIN r.subscriptions s WHERE (s.subscriptionName in (:subscriptionList))")
Page<User> findAllBySubscriptions(@Param("subscriptionList") Set<String> subscriptionList, Pageable pageable);
```

But this query is populating duplicate entries if more than one element in `subscriptionList` matches with actual `ReaderEntity.subscriptions`.

I cannot use `Distinct` because the pageable contains sort order which sorts the list by usernames case insensitive. So it appends `order by lower(username)` at the end and it throws the error:

```
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

Can anyone please help me to formulate this query or guide me in direction on how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

use the hint [pass distinct through](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/QueryHints.html#PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH)

as in

```
@QueryHints(@QueryHint(name = org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, value = "false"))
@Query("SELECT distinct r FROM ReaderEntity r LEFT JOIN r.subscriptions s WHERE (s.subscriptionName in (:subscriptionList))")
Page<User> findAllBySubscriptions(@Param("subscriptionList") Set<String> subscriptionList, Pageable pageable);
```