# Hibernate Query to match mapped entity collection with at least one element in given collection,and must not match in another, ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

My owner Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "SubscriptionEntity")
@Table(name = "SUBSCRIPTION", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID")})
 
public class SubscriptionEntity implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer subscriptionId;
 
    @Column(name = "SUBS_NAME", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String subscriptionName;
     
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="READER_SUBSCRIPTIONS", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="ID")}
                                        , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="ID")})
    private Set<ReaderEntity> readers;
 
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Mapped Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "ReaderEntity")
@Table(name = "READER", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "EMAIL"),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "USERNAME"})
 
public class ReaderEntity implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer readerId;
 
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String email;
 
    @Column(name = "USERNAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String username;
 
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="readers") 
    private Set<SubscriptionEntity> subscriptions;
 
    //Getters and setters
}
```

Now, I have a `subscriptionList` which contains few subscriptions. I wanted a paged list of `ReaderEntity` objects whose subscriptions belong to at least one in the `subscriptionList`. i.e. The intersection of `ReaderEntity.subscriptions` and `subscriptionList` should be at least one.

I have referred to this post and written a query:
[Hibernate or SQL Query M-N member of with collections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846512/hibernate-or-sql-query-m-n-member-of-with-collections)

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT r FROM ReaderEntity r LEFT JOIN r.subscriptions s WHERE (s.subscriptionName in (:subscriptionList))")
Page<User> findAllBySubscriptions(@Param("subscriptionList") Set<String> subscriptionList, Pageable pageable);
```

This achieves my goal of fetching readers having at least one common in `ReaderEntity.subscriptions` and `subscriptionList`.

**What I want to achieve:**

Now, I have a `restrictedSubscriptionList` which is a collection of `SubscriptionEntity` (can be `SubscriptionEntity.name`). Now I want to extend the above query so that, if the reader is subscribed to any one in the `restrictedSubscriptionList`, then it won't be fetched. Which means, if the intersection between `ReaderEntity.subscriptions` and `restrictedSubscriptionList` is not null, then the Reader should not be fetched.

**What I tried so far**:
I tried adding `AND NOT IN (:restrictedSubscriptionList)` to that query but it seems to have wrong logic and still populates all the readers with having subscribed to at least one of the restrictedSubscriptionList.

I manually fetched the readers belonging to those `restrictedSubscriptionList` and added them to exclude as:

`WHERE r.username NOT IN (:restrictedSubscriptionList)`

But when such readers become more, the query will become huge, resulting in reduced efficiency.

If anyone can help me formulating the query, it will be really appreciated.

Thank you so much for taking the time and reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't and shouldn't filter the collection of an entity for various reasons. The best you can do is to only select those `ReaderEntity` objects that fit your requirements. You can use a query like the following which is better in terms of result set cardinality:

```
from ReaderEntity r 
where exists (
  select 1 
  from r.subscriptions s 
  where s.subscriptionName in :subscriptionList 
  and s.subscriptionName not in :restrictedSubscriptionList
)
```